# Magento2 - Layered navigation issue

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I have a `Magento2.3.4` installation.

The issue is that the product count on layered navigation is wrong. When I am selecting an option the products showing on the grid are correct.

Comment: Are here any custom modules installed that might be the issue? If so temporally disable each one by one to test.